# After dismissViewController my view remain in previous view controller's orientation in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, navigation, uiinterfaceorientation

As I am working with iOS application support only `Portrait Orientation`.
But I am getting some Orientation related issue.

- My app support only portrait orientation
- when my parent **P1.view** is push using navigation it is in portrait mode thats fine. Now from **P1.view** I am subviewing my child view **C1.view**
- Now I am in childview **C1.view** and from there using delegate I am calling

  -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker

  `[self.delegate openCamera]`;//called from C1.view

  ```
  -(void)openCamera   //declared in P1.view
      {
          UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
          picker.delegate = self;
          picker.allowsEditing = NO;
          picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;>             
          [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
      }
  ```
- Now when I capture photo in Lanscape mode and dismiss that
  presentModalViewController my view appears in Landscapmode instead of Portrait
  mode.

  ```
      - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
          return YES;
      }
      - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
       return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
              interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
      }

      - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {    
          return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
      }
      - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
          return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
      }
  ```

This methods are define in both the view controller(P1 & C1) and also called  when modelview dismiss, but​ my viewcontroller remains in Landscape which should ​not be happen.

This code working fine in iOS6 but not iOS7

Comment: For iOS 7 you should use **-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration** But this won't work in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` is not supposed to return a bit mask. You could try:

`- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }`